# Using a function in Array.map

Tags: f#

I need a function that will replace a number (numberToBrake) of items in an array with the broken variant of a thing and return the new array of things. The function below seems like it should work but the result type signature is (('b -> 'c ) [])
What am i doing wrong here? Many thanks

```
let BrakeThings things numberToBrake =
    Array.map  (fun el i ->  (if i < numberToBrake then BrokenThing else HealthyThing)) things
```

Comment: `Array.map` only takes in a single parameter. If you want the index as well, use `Array.mapi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wanting the `mapi` function here which exposes the index as an function parameter:

```ml
let brakeThings things numberToBrake =
    things 
    |> Array.mapi (fun el a ->  
        if i < numberToBrake then BrokenThing 
        else HealthyThing)
```